# Where can I look up the yet highest used cpu speed on my computer?

Tags: windows, cpu, windows-8.1

Is there a log where I can look up the yet highest performed speed of my cpu on windows 8.1? For example if I wanted to know if the cpu was overclocked at some point.

Comment: Unless you overclock it, then it wasn't overclocked, but past cpu speeds are not logged in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

This sort of information is not stored unfortunately, so you will be unable to retrieve this data.

Assuming your PC was new when you bought it - then unless you overclocked it yourself, it was never overclocked.

If the PC is second hand (you aren't the first owner) then the only way to know if it was ever overclocked would be to ask the previous owner.

Sorry

Answer (score 0):

This tool called [TMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/tmonitor.html) or [PerfMonitor 2](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/perfmonitor2.html)may helpful to you!

[image: TMonitor]

[image: PerfMonitor 2]

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the other's answers, you can look inside the BIOS/UEFI for the CPU speeds.
In UEFI it's on the default page (simplified page), at the top right corner. "Speed: 3100MHz".

[image: pic]